# Added isolcpus to Grub, restarted but cat /proc/cmdline doesn't show it added

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel, grub2

I've added isolcpus to the Grub file:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash isolcpus=2,3"
```

Restarted machine (Ubuntu 22.04)

However, when I run:

```
cat /proc/cmdline
```

it doesn't show my isolcpus change:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-43-generic root=UUID=d0731368-37f5-4a83-84d9-a899d39f5a59 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

I can also see interrupts on those 2 cores.

Am I missing something to get this to work?

Comment: @thrig sudo'd it with vi, edited, saved, restarted machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merely editing the grub configuration does not suffice; a command must be run to rebuild the grub menu. [On ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup), this command is `update-grub` so after editing the configuration file one must run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and only then reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you know much about isolcpus? I'm still seeing "Function call interrupts" increment for the two cores i've isolated

Comment: That probably should be done in a new question, or see if the existing ones shed any light.